# object Promise on return

Tags: node.js, object, promise, return

Whenever I'm trying to generate random keys from crypto or nanoid (new library) it just returns [object Promise]

```
async function createCode(length){
  if(!length){
    return nanoid;
  } else {
    return nanoid(length);
  }
}

// another one for example
async function createCode(){
  return await crypto.randomBytes(64).toString('hex');
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All async function return a promise.   Always.

So, the caller of an async function has to either use `await` themselves (from within another `async` function) or use `.then()` to get the value out of the promise.

It doesn't look to me like either of your functions benefit from being async.   `return await someFunc()` when `someFunc()` returns a promise can be done with just `return someFunc()` just the same.  The `await` is not necessary at all.

FYI, `crypto.randomBytes()` uses a callback if you want the asynchronous version.  If you don't pass it a callback, then it's just a plain synchronous function.  Unless you've done something to make a promisified version of that library, it doesn't return a promise.

So, you can just use this:

```
// another one for example
function createCode(){
  return crypto.randomBytes(64).toString('hex');
}
```

Which you can just call as a regular function:

```
let randomVal = createCode();
console.log(randomVal);
```

If you want the asynchronous version and want to use it with promises, then you'd have to promisify it:

```
// another one for example
function createCode(){
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
       crypto.randomBytes(64, function(err, val) {
           if (err) return reject(err);
           resolve(val.toString('hex'));
       });
  });

}
```

Then, you can call it:

```
 createCode().then(val => {
     console.log(val);
 }).catch(err => {
     console.log(err);
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

An async function returns a promise by default. Please call await createCode() in another async function or use createCode().then()